# Use @Before in service for all methods in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, service, crud

I am implementing a `service` for my controller in java. This service implements an interface with several methods, where each of them performs a different logic. However, they also have a common logic (they must call another @service).
I would like to know if there is any way to refactor this, that is, remove that common logic that they have to a method in the class of my service that is executed only once, at the beginning.

I'm looking for something similar to the following:

```
public class myClass implements myInterface{

private String stringToFill="";

@Before
public doSomeLogig(){
   // call another service
   stringToFill = "filled";
}

public getAll(){
   ...
   //here I should use stringToFill, with value 'filled'
}
public getId(){
   //here I should use stringToFill, with value 'filled'
   ...
}
public create(){
   //here I should use stringToFill, with value 'filled'
   ...
}
```

}

Comment: Take care of java naming conventions. Class and Interface names should start with upper case character

Comment: Read abut `@PostConstruct`, if this is a spring bean

Comment: BTW: `@Before` is from junit i guess? If so, do not use it in production code

Comment: @Jens it is just a pseudo-code

Comment: Another way of solving this would be to have an `abstract class` implementing the interface and extends the children classes with this new class

Comment: @LeonardoEmmanueldeAzevedo How this helps by fullfilling the requirement *class of my service that is executed only once, at the beginning*?

Comment: @Jens It doesn't, I missed that part, apologies. I'd stick with your suggestion, using `@PostConstruct`

Answer (score 0):

There is a spring lifecycle annotation called as @PostConstruct, write a method in the class and add all the one time execution logic in this method and annotate it with the @PostConstruct annotation and spring would call this method automatically once the bean has been initialized.

Answer (score -1):

Using AOP you can call a method in lots of different scenarios including the one you described.
Here is Link to Spring AOP documentation
[Spring AOP](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/2.5.5/reference/aop.html#:%7E:text=Aspect-Oriented%20Programming%20(AOP),of%20modularity%20is%20the%20aspect.)

```
@Aspect
public class BeforeExample {

  @Before("com.xyz.myapp.SystemArchitecture.dataAccessOperation()")
  public void doAccessCheck() {
    // ...
  }

}
```

You can Also define a custom annotation like @Before to do the magic for you.

Comment: But this will be executed every time the methos will be called, no only once as OP is expected. Thats why I think AOP is not the right solution

Comment: There is already `@PostConstruct` which will execute code after the object has been constructed and autowired. Doing this with AOP is overkill.